# How to change Page set up Orientation from Portrait to Landscape in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I generate a document via Google Apps Script.

Is there a way to change `Page setup...` > `Orientation` from `Portrait` to `Landscape`?

The document contains tables that only display well in `Landscape` mode, and I'd like to be able to:

- Generate the document
- Change Orientation from Portrait to Landscape
- Convert document to PDF and send to user

**Convert to PDF and send**

```
// create the document
var doc = DocumentApp.create('Sample Document - Landscape Mode');
var body = doc.getBody();
// add lots of content...
// ensure all content is added to the PDF
// see:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44481513/1063287
doc.saveAndClose();
// create the pdf file
var pdf_file = doc.getAs("application/pdf");

// see:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)
 GmailApp.sendEmail('user@test.com', 'Attachment example', 'Please see the attached file.', {
     attachments: [pdf_file],
     name: 'Test Name'
 });
```

If not officially supported, I'd be interested to know if there were any hacky methods of achieving the same effect (something like: url parameters to enforce landscape mode, programmatic rotating of pdf file, getting Google Apps Script to create the page in Landscape mode by default?)

**Edit:**

In `Page setup...` > `Orientation`, there is an option to `Set as default`.

I clicked that and ran the script, and it creates the document in `Landscape` mode and then sends the PDF out in `Landscape` mode, which is great, but it just means that whenever I want to create a document manually in `Portrait` mode, I have to manually change the `Orientation` to `Portrait`.  Additionally, if I want another function to create a document in `Portrait` mode, this solution would not work.

So some progress, but would still like to know if there is a more comprehensive solution.

**Edit 2:**

I tried this approach in the browser viewing a document in `Portrait`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35344694/1063287

Ie, I replaced:

```
/edit
```

at the end of the url with:

```
export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&portrait=false
```

But the document downloaded in `Portrait` orientation.

Comment: Try setting portrait to false, portrait=false, when exporting the PDF. Check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35909624/change-document-orientation-when-exporting-to-pdf) for more code implementation.

Answer (score 7):

I was looking into the exact same thing when I came over your question, and eventually found the answer, so I might as well share it here.
This link explains a solution quite well:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/HuwBipQ6cBY

You need to manually set the dimensions (in points) of the paper in your code.
The code in the above link uses dimensions in decimals. 
I did however find some recommended measurements here using whole numbers:
https://www.prepressure.com/library/paper-size/din-a4

This is how I would create a new Document, and set it to A4 landscape:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.create("Document name");
var docBody = doc.getBody();
docBody.setPageHeight(595).setPageWidth(842);
```

And here is a quote from the first link using values in decimal numbers.

Quote from first link:

> Rotate to landscape, A4 size

```
doc.getBody().setPageHeight(595.276).setPageWidth(841.89);
```

> Rotate to portrait, A4 size

```
doc.getBody().setPageHeight(841.89).setPageWidth(595.276);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Moderators perm-deleted my first answer before I could apply my edit. Bit mean, but I understand. Here is the rewised answer.