# How to getAs("application/pdf") a newly created document in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't have access to `DriveApp` but am trying to email a PDF of a newly created document with:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.create('Sample Document');
var body = doc.getBody();
// create lots of content in the document...
//
// after adding all the content and applying styles etc
// send the document as PDF to the user
var pdf_file = doc.getAs("application/pdf");
GmailApp.sendEmail('user@test.com', 'Attachment example', 'Please see the attached file.', {
     attachments: [pdf_file],
     name: 'Test Name'
 });
```

The PDF attachment received, however, is a blank document and I *think* this is because the document is being "got" as a PDF file before the contents have been added to the document.

Is there any way for Google Apps Script to either:

- Wait until the content has been added before converting to PDF?
- Ensure that `getAs()` uses a "refreshed" version of `doc` (that has all the added contents)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The PDF attachment received, however, is a blank document and I think this is because the document is being "got" as a PDF file before the contents have been added to the document.

Correct, add the line: `doc.saveAndClose();` to the end of the code that builds the doc.