# Export Google Sheet to PDF Programmatically with Custom Parameters

Tags: pdf, google-sheets, google-drive-api

How do you export an entire Google Sheet to PDF in Landscape with fit to width, grid lines, page numbers, and spreadsheet name but not sheet name?

How about exporting the same as above but only 1 specific sheet in the spreadsheet or specific range within a sheet?

I can do all this through the GUI when exporting from a Google Sheet but no documented way via API.

I have found various sources showing how to do this via URL but have been unable to find any documentation by Google. The parameters used are not consist between sources and have been unable to figure out all the parameters available through the GUI.

How were the parameters determined? Is this documented by Google? Is this possible via API?

URL exporting sources:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761058#c25

[Google Apps Script - Add landscape parameter to PDF email attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288617/google-apps-script-add-landscape-parameter-to-pdf-email-attachment)

Comment: did you have any success with that?

Comment: I used trial and error. Ended up with the following: 
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + //export as pdf
  //below parameters are optional...
  '&size=letter' + //paper size
  '&portrait=false' + //orientation, false for landscape
  '&fitw=true' + //fit to width, false for actual size
  '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=true&pagenumber=true' + //hide optional headers and footers //pagenumbers/pagenumber/pagenum/page does not appear to work.
  '&gridlines=true' + //hide gridlines
  '&fzr=false'; //do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page

Comment: This answer from Google Support seems to list all of the options: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3457043?hl=en